# Prove that $\text{trace}(X^T Y)\le \sqrt{\text{trace}(X^T X)\text{trace}(Y^T Y)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, trace

As the title says, I would like help with proving that:

$$
\text{trace}(X^T Y)\le \sqrt{\text{trace}(X^T X)\text{trace}(Y^T Y)}
$$

where $X,Y\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

Perhaps this has to do with the Cauchy inequality, but I am not sure how to apply in.

Comment: Can you show that $\textrm{tr}: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}, (X, Y) \mapsto \textrm{trace}(X^TY)$ is a pre-inner product?

Comment: I found the solution by writing $(XY)_{jj}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ji}y_{ij}$, applying this to the case $X^T Y$, $X^T X$ and $Y^T Y$ and then using cauchy-schwarz.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) for the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).